# How do I specify external assets in Angular?

Tags: angular

In Angular, the location of assets have to be specified in angular.json. I.e.:

> "assets": [
> "src/favicon.ico",
> "src/assets",
> "src/app/home/assets/img"
> ],

I have to use images that do not reside on Angular: I.e.:

> https://thehill.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2022/05/cropped-favicon.png?w=180

the call from Angular is like so:

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4"
    *ngFor="let site of category.sites">
    <a class="card-link" href="#">
       <h6 class="text-muted d-flex justify-content-center mb-2" style="font-size: 20px;">
      {{site.url}}
       </h6>
       <img class="img-fluid news-logo" src="{{site.img}}">
    </a> 
</div>
```

Angular is not displaying the images. I am supposing it is because the location is not registered in angular.json as an asset. How do I handle this?

Comment: tried this `<img src="https://thehill.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2022/05/cropped-favicon.png?w=180" >` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the external url in the img tag inside of your component html file:

```
<img src="https://thehill.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2022/05/cropped-favicon.png?w=180" >
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-open7p?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: I am iterating over a bunch of images, the image is not hard coded as you proposed. I have modified my original question to show this.

Comment: could you please add a stackbliz link so that we can see what is exactly inside of `category.sites` ?